# Where does VS2012 run my asp.net code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a asp.net Project in VS2012

In this project I create some files and now I want to view them in my File explorere, the problem:

I dont know where VS2012 run my project. Which is the path where I can find the files which are running under `localhost:498xx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files might be hidden, try clicking **"Show All files"** on top right corner of the VS.

Also if you right click any project, there is an option **"Open Folder in File Explorer"**.